# How can I do this in shell?

Tags: shell

I'm very new in shell programming and this is the homework I have for my lab. I really can not understand what I should do and how. Can anyone help me?

Write a shell that begining with a given folder displays a list of all
names: files and folders from it and its subdirectories.
For each text file from list, name prints the maximum number
of identical lines from the that file, and the content of those line.
For each folder names from the list, the number of contained files will be
printed.

Comment: you tried? look: [http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

Comment: you tried? look: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html

Comment: You'll need basic shell commands that you can learn about in the above mentioned manuals: `ls`, `wc`, `uniq`, `sort`, `cat` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
find $1 | while read name
do  echo $name
    case `file $name` in
    *text)      sort $name|uniq -c|sort -nr|head -1;;
    *directory) find $name -maxdepth 1 -type f|wc -w;;
    esac
done
```